# COUNT / GROUP BY with active record?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, count, group-by

I have a table with the following info:

```
id  |  user_id  |  points
--------------------------
1   |  12       |  48
2   |  15       |  36
3   |  18       |  22
4   |  12       |  28
5   |  15       |  59
6   |  12       |  31

etc.
```

What I want is a top 10 (array) with most entries per user_id (order high to low).
So using the table above I need the following array in return:

- 12 => 3 rows
- 15 => 2 rows
- 18 => 1 row
- etc.

How can I do this with CodeIgniter using the active record query method? Can this be done with COUNT and GROUP BY user_id?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I believe you'll want something like this:

```
 $this->db->select('user_id, COUNT(user_id) as total');
 $this->db->group_by('user_id'); 
 $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc'); 
 $this->db->get('tablename', 10);
```

This will produce a result like

```
|  USER_ID |  TOTAL  |
|    12    |    3    |
|    15    |    2    |
|    18    |    1    |
```

**UPDATE:** As some pointed out in the comments the original query was summing the user_ids rather than counting them. I've updated the active record query to correct this.

Comment: You could also use the function `$this->db->last_query()` to see what active record generated from the functions [User Guide: Query Helper Functions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html)

Comment: That works too, though you often need to change a bunch of CI settings so it doesn't throw an error when it tries to run an invalid query.

Comment: This answer sums the user_ids rather than counting them.

Comment: Sums the keys rather than counting them. For user id 12 this would output: 36 which is of course undesired!

Comment: I'd like to point out that it counts the ids not the rows.. thats why vote down.

Comment: I've updated my answer to `COUNT` rather than `SUM` the `user_id`s.

Comment: $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.
the first line should be

`$this->db->select('user_id, COUNT(user_id) as total', FALSE);`

Answer (score 9):

Although it is a late answer, I would say this will help you...

```
$query = $this->db
              ->select('user_id, count(user_id) AS num_of_time')
              ->group_by('user_id')
              ->order_by('num_of_time', 'desc')
              ->get('tablename', 10);
print_r($query->result());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should count the results with [FOUND_ROWS() and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows). You'll need two queries: `select`, `group_by`, etc. You'll add a plus select: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS user_id`. After this query run a query: `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`. This will return the desired number.

Answer (score 1):

This code counts rows with date range:

Controller:

```
$this->load->model("YourModelName");
$data ['query'] = $this->YourModelName->get_report();
```

Model:

```
  public function get_report()
     {   
       $query = $this->db->query("SELECT  *
FROM   reservation WHERE arvdate <= '2016-7-20' AND  dptrdate >= '2016-10-25' ");
       return $query;
     }
```

where 'arvdate' and 'dptrdate'  are two dates on database and 'reservation' is the table name.

View:

```
<?php
 echo $query->num_rows();
?>
```

This code is to return number of rows. 
To return table data, then use

```
$query->rows();
return $row->table_column_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('overal_points');
$this->db->where('point_publish', 1);
$this->db->order_by('overal_points', 'desc'); 
$query = $this->db->get('company', 4)->result();
```