# Count and display how many of specific column result

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have the following table

```
|id|city|job|
|12|New York|Truck driver|
|13|Chicago|Postman|
|14|New York|Postman|
|15|Las Vegas|Dealer|
|16|Las Vegas|Dealer|
|17|New York|Post Office|
```

I want to be able to count how many jobs there is in each city and then return the ten cities with most job in an DESC order. Like the following

- New York (3)
- Las Vegas (2)
- Chicago (1)

How do I accomplish this?

My code looks like this

```
 $this->db->select('city');
 $this->db->select_sum('city', 'total');
 $this->db->group_by('city'); 
 $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc'); 
 $query = $this->db->get('job', 10);

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = array(
        'total' => $row->total,
        'city' => $row->city
    );
}

return $data;
```

I took inspiration from this thread: [COUNT / GROUP BY with active record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988268/codeigniter-count-group-by-with-active-record)

But doesn't seems to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:-

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT city, COUNT(city) AS jobcount FROM `jobs` GROUP BY city ORDER BY jobcount DESC');

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
        $data[] = array(
            'total' => $row->jobcount,
            'city'  => $row->city
        );

return $data;
```

Dont forget to swap `'jobs'` with your table name

Comment: Perhaps add a limit(mysql /TOP for mssql)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `$this->db->query();?`

```
$this->db->query('SELECT CITY, COUNT(CITY) AS TOTAL FROM JOB GROUP BY CITY ORDER BY TOTAL DESC LIMIT 10');
```