# How to display total count of specific field from database column using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display in View specific field value from Database.

For example my table:

```
                            id  |  rec_scope  |  rec_category
                            --------------------------
                            1   |  Product      |  New
                            2   |  Process      |  Enhance
                            3   |  Process      |  New
                            4   |  System       |  Enhance
                            5   |  Product      |  New
                            6   |  Process      |  New
                            7   |  Product      |  Enhance
                            8   |  System       |  New
                            9   |  Product      |  New
                            10  |  Prcduct      |  New
```

I got inspiration from:

[COUNT / GROUP BY with active record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988268/count-group-by-with-active-record) and [Count and display how many of specific column result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290637/count-and-display-how-many-of-specific-column-result)

Controller:

```
                            public function index()
                            {

                                $data['records_count']= $this->dashboard_m->records_count();
                                $data['records_scope']= $this->dashboard_m->records_scope();


                                $this->template->load('template', 'dashboard', $data);


                            }
```

Model:

```
                            public function records_scope() {
                                 $this->db->select('rec_scope, COUNT(rec_scope) as total');
                                 $this->db->group_by('rec_scope');
                                 $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc');
                                 $query = $this->db->get('records');


                                foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
                                    $data[] = array(
                                        'rec_scope'  => $row->rec_scope,
                                        'total'  => $row->total
                                    );



                                return $data;

                            }
```

How can I display in html view only the total count of specific field with specific value? Thank you.

Example:

Total count of Product is 5.

Total count Category of Product as New is 4.

Total count Category of Product as Enhance is 1.

Comment: what is your desired output? And your table example has a typo in Line 10: `Prcduct` should be `Product`, right?

Comment: @Vickel Yes..its just a typo..but it doesn't matter actually.  Btw, I just need to display the value of total count of specific table field i.e Product. So the output will also display the total count of category "New" & "Enhance" Product..Tq

Comment: check #4 here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-count/#4

Comment: an example array output would be nice. i'm assuming you don't just want product. but e.g. `array('product' => array('new => '4', 'enhance' => '1'), ('process' => .... etc )` ?

Comment: Thank you @Vickel. You give me some insight to progress. I will research more and try again

Comment: Hi @Alex. Yes. You're right. Perhaps I should use Join query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably yield the results you are after:

```
    $this->db->select('*, COUNT(rec_scope) as count');
    $this->db->from('test');
    $this->db->group_by('rec_category, rec_scope');
    $this->db->order_by('rec_scope');
    $res = $this->db->get()->result();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($res as $item) {
        // initialize total
        if (!isset($data[$item->rec_scope]['Total'])) {
            $data[$item->rec_scope]['Total'] = 0;
        }
        $data[$item->rec_scope]['Total'] += $item->count;
        $data[$item->rec_scope][$item->rec_category] = $item->count;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot  @Alex. It looks like what I'm trying to achieve. I will try first and feedback later.