# display total number of clients product

Tags: codeigniter

Hello i having a problem with displaying the number of the attached products to the client and not the total number of products in db.

### So here is my code

```
<div class="span2 action-nav-button">

                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?client/product">

                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>template/images/icons/product.png" />

                    <span><?php echo get_phrase('manage_product');?></span>

                    <span class="label label-blue">

                        **<?php echo $this->db->count_all_results('product');?>**

                    </span>

                    </a>

                </div>
```

---

As you can see it displays 297 products (total) and not 7 as it supposed to. In what do i need to modify this line ( db->count_all_results('product');?>) to display the correct nubmer? Thank you in advance !

-image-> http://postimg.org/image/bb1ce26nv/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988268/codeigniter-count-group-by-with-active-record

Comment: adding proper code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Use `num_rows()`:

```
$productsQuery = 'SELECT * FROM product WHERE clientid = "SOME_CLIENT_ID" ';
$query = $this->db->query($productsQuery);

echo $query->num_rows();
```

Of course, replace `clientid` with the actual field in your product table. Or adjust the request to get only the products for the client you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! :) I am not a developer but i am trying to fix since the developer is missing :) 

I see my tables in database and it has clients and product -  On my files i have ONE file in Views folder dashboard which is i guess a common file for everyone .

So i wonter how can i modify this common file

Comment: I guess you'll have to find the proper SQL request and the replace the PHP code you pasted in your question by the one I provided to you (with the right request).