# MySQL Query to Select dependent rows from Joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on a codeigniter project.

Here are my tables

```
category
cid cname
5   general
6   science
7   math

books
bid bname
12  first
13  second
14  third
15  fourth
16  fifth
17  sixth

dir
id  bid     cid
1   12      5
2   13      6
3   14      7
4   15      6
5   16      5
6   17      5
```

As you can see joining the tables is easy but here is what I need to do.

Create a function that will give me category name(cname) and the number of books in that category. For example the outcome should be like

```
general 3
science 2
math    1
```

here is my WIP model

```
function category_details(){
        $this->db->order_by('cname','asc');
        $query=$this->db->query('Select * from dir join category on category.cid=dir.cid join books on dir.bid=books.bid');
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what's output now ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be like this to get expected result

```
Select category.cname,count(dir.cid) from dir join category on category.cid=dir.cid join books on dir.bid=books.bid group by category.cname
```

And your function should be like this

```
function category_details(){
        $this->db->order_by('cname','asc');
        $query=$this->db->query('Select category.cname,count(dir.cid) from dir join category on category.cid=dir.cid join books on dir.bid=books.bid group by category.cname');
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

you can refer this code [COUNT / GROUP BY with active record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988268/count-group-by-with-active-record) for proper CI query.